# Getting value from checked box in angular 2 typescript

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using Angular 2 Typescript. I am facing a problem wherein I need to submit a form which contains check boxes. I need values that are in the attributes of checkboxes. The checkboxes are dynamic, so any number of checkboxes will be there.

```html
 <div class="checkbox" *ngFor="#label of labelList">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
           <label><input type="checkbox" value="{{label.Id}}">{{ label.Name }}</label>
      </div>   
 </div>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think this should work (not tested)

```
<div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let label of labelList">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="{{label.Id}}" (change)="checkboxes[$event.target.getAttribute('value')]=$event.target.checked">
        {{ label.Name }}</label>
  </div>   
</div>
```

and store the values of changed checkboxes in `checkboxes` in your component.

Comment: And what will be on typescript (angular2)  side. what will be the function ?

Comment: No function, just an object `checkboxes` that contains the values of the changed checkboxes. If you provide more information about what you actually try to accomplish I might be able to make more suggestions.

Comment: console the value of checkbox ?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your comment? `console.debug(this.checkboxes)`?

Comment: What about you providing more information about your requirements first?

Answer (score 2):

I use this for the checkboxes:
[ng2-material checkbox](https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material/blob/master/ng2-material/components/checkbox/checkbox.ts)

And you could do this in your component:

```
<md-checkbox [checked]="exists(label.Id)" (click)="toggle(label.Id)"></md-checkbox>

  selected = [];
  @Output() selectedChange:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  toggle(id) {
    var index = this.selected.indexOf(id);
    if (index === -1) this.selected.push(id);
    else this.selected.splice(index, 1);
    this.selectedChange.emit(this.selected);
  }

  exists(id) {
    return this.selected.indexOf(id) > -1;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Input**

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="selectionChange($event.srcElement, dataItem)">
```

**Change Event**

```
selectionChange(input: HTMLInputElement) {
    input.checked === true
      ? doSomethingIfTrue()
      : doSomethingIfFalse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `name` attribute for checkbox to able to track it on backend.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

```js
submitForm(form:NgForm){
console.log(form.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox" *ngFor="#label of labelList">
       <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name='label{{label.Id}}'  value="{{label.Id}}">{{ label.Name }} </label>
       </div>   
 </div>
```

Use name attribute including label.id,so you will get all value in array form.

GUESS THIS WILL HELP.

Answer (score -4):

I think you want to know checkbox that checked or not which you can easily get in the form of boolean value by specifying ng-model attribute for input tag attribute.

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.someBooleanValue"></md-checkbox>
```

for more info check [angular material md-checkbox](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdCheckbox) and [angular material md-checkbox demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/checkbox)

Comment: The question asks for help with Angular 2; "ng-model" is Angular 1 syntax.